# Quando usar vertical-align?

Tags: posicionamento, css

Tenho noção de que em certos casos é recomendável usar essa propriedade ao invés de `text-align` , `margin` ou `position`.

Mas não sei porque e nem como funciona o `vertical-align`.

Além disso, como é que se usa essa propriedade?

Comment: A `vertical-align`serve para alinhar textos verticalmente que estejam dentro de uma célula de tabela ou uma linha. Já o `horizontal-align` eu nunca ouvi falar.

Comment: Que gafe. Man, mas para essa função já não existe o line-height?

Comment: É que usando `line-height` você não está alinhando o elemento e sim aumentando o tamanho da linha para forçar uma centralização. Um caso: Se precisar alterar o `height` do elemento consequentemente o `line-height` também precisará de mudança, certo? A proposta do `vertical-align` é centralizar o elemento verticalmente independente da altura.

Comment: @ropbla9 pense em uma mesma linha que tenha uma palavra com fonte 12, uma com fonte 18, e uma imagem _inline_. O vertical-align vai decidir se alinha tudo pelo meio, ou pela _baseline_ (parte de baixo das letras), ou pelo topo das três coisas, ou pela parte de baixo, por exemplo. PS: Escrevi pra dar uma noção inicial, se alguém quiser postar resposta com essas informações e der uma elaborada melhor, fique à vontade.

Answer (score 4):

Use `vertical-align` para centralizar verticalmente um elemento em seu "pai". Ao contrário de `text-align` essa não ajusta horizontalmente o texto, mas verticalmente todo o conteúdo do elemento.

Pode ter os seguintes valores:

```
test{
    vertical-align: baseline; /* Alinha o elemento com a base do elemento pai. Essa é a opção padrão */
    vertical-align: *px; /* Alinha o elemento a * pixels da sua posição inicial. Use valores negativos para elevar o elemento */
    vertical-align: sub; /* Alinha o elemento como subescrito em relação à posição padrão. */
    vertical-align: super;  /* Alinha o elemento como superescrito em relação à posição padrão. */
    vertical-align: top; /* O elemento é alinhado pela margem superior do elemento mais alto da linha. */   
    vertical-align: text-top; /* O elemento é alinhado pelo topo da fonte do elemento "pai". */
    vertical-align: middle; /* O elemento é colocado verticalmente no centro do elemento pai. */
    vertical-align: bottom; /* O elemento é alinhado pela margem inferior do elemento mais abaixo da linha. */  
}
```

```js
var state = 0;
var states = ["baseline","-20px","sub","super","top","text-top","middle","bottom","text-bottom"]; 
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        state += 1;
        if(state > 8){ state = 0; }
        alert(states[state]);
        $("#move").css("vertical-align", states[state]); 
        $("#move").text("vertical-align: " + states[state] + ";");
    });
});
```

```css
div{
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pai">
  <center>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vzckf2Z.png" />
    Texto
    <img id="move" src="http://i.imgur.com/1EFwogv.png" />
    
  </center>
</div>
<button id="btn">Mover!</button>
```

Comment: Resumindo: line-height aumenta o espaçamento do parágrafo e vertical-align alinha um elemento verticalmente. Ok?

Comment: `line-height` aumenta o espaçamento da linha propriamente dita. Elementos com `display: inline` por exemplo não aumentarão a altura de todo o parágrafo, mas apenas até o fim do elemento.

Comment: Resumindo: o mesmo que eu disse.